# Margins not setting to zero

Tags: html, css

I set the margins in between my article tag and my header tag to 0, but I still see a space between them that shows my body in yellow. I'm trying to minimize the space between the header and article to 0 without setting all the elements in the body to marin: 0

Here is my CSS.

```
body 
{
background-color: yellow;
margin: 0;
}

header > * {
margin: 0;
float: left;
}

header
{
background-color: white ;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;

}

article > * {
margin: 0;
}

article
{
background-color: red;
}

#search {
background-color: #a6dbed;
height: 500px;
}

#mostdesired 
{
background-color: #c7d1d6;
height: 200px;
}
```

and here is the html

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </header>
    <article>
        <section id="search"><h2>this is the search</h2>@RenderBody()</section>
        <section id="mostdesired" ><h2>This is the most section</h2></section>
    </article>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the default margins from the `<h2>` elements:

```
section h2 {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4m2ZF/)**

Comment: @circusdei - however the OP said "I'm trying to minimize the space between the header and article to 0 without setting all the elements in the body to marin: 0"

Comment: I'm basically trying to create a header and body like www.airbnb.com has with no space in between. There might be a better way then what I'm doing but I'm a newbie!

Comment: I tried removing the margin:0 from the H2 tag but that didn't work

Comment: You did see that it works in the fiddle though right?

Comment: yes it worked. thanks. Can anyone suggest any better way to create a header and article that looks like www.airbnb.com?